# Rails Strong Parameters - Allow parameter to be an Array or String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strong-parameters

Using **Strong Parameters** in my Rails Controller, how can I state that a permitted parameter can be a `String` or an `Array`?

**My strong params:**

```
class SiteSearchController < ApplicationController
    [...abbreviated for brevity...]

    private
    def search_params
        params.fetch(:search, {}).permit(:strings)
    end
end
```

I'm wanting to `POST` string(s) to search as a `String` or as an `Array`:

**To search for 1 thing:**

```
{
    "strings": "search for this"
}
```

**OR, to search for multiple things:**

```
{
    "strings": [
        "search for this",
        "and for this",
        "and search for this string too"
    ]
}
```

---

**Update:**

**Purpose:** I'm creating an API where my users can "batch" requests (getting responses via `web-hooks`), or make a one-off request (getting an immediate response) all on the same endpoint. This question is only 1 small part of my requirement.

The next piece will be doing this same logic, where I'll allow the search to happen on multiple pages, i.e.:

```
[
    {
        "page": "/section/look-at-this-page",
        "strings": "search for this"
    },
    {
        "page": "/this-page",
        "strings": [
            "search for this",
            "and for this",
            "and search for this string too"
        ]
    }
]
```

**OR on a single page:**

```
{
    "page": "/section/look-at-this-page",
    "strings": "search for this"
}
```

(which will make me need to have **Strong Params** allow an `Object` or an `Array` to be sent.

This seems like a basic thing, but I'm not seeing anything out there.

I know that I could just make the `strings` param an array, and then require searching for 1 thing to just have 1 value in the array... but I want to have this parameter be more robust than that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could check if `params[:strings]` is an array and work from there

```
def strong_params
  if params[:string].is_a? Array
    params.fetch(:search, {}).permit(strings: [])
  else 
    params.fetch(:search, {}).permit(:strings)
  end
end
```

Comment: Oh snap, that's brilliant!

Answer (score 48):

You can just permit the parameter twice - once for an array and once for a scalar value.

```
def search_params
    params.fetch(:search, {}).permit(:strings, strings: [])
end
```

Comment: I haven't tested this, but that's clever. Thank you @tombeynon!

Comment: It's actually even possible to allow multiple types like so: `params.permit(:attr, { :attr => [] }, { :attr => {} })`. However, as much as I like this behaviour, I couldn't find it anywhere in the documentation... It works, though.

Comment: BRILLIANT! Would've never thought of that! :D

Comment: Still works in rails 7, however, in my case, order mattered and I had to put the scalar value before the array. Otherwise, a syntax error was thrown..